# Flutter FCM can't run onBackgroundMessage, can't save notifications locally when not clicked

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using flutter to make an android app and one of the features is to show and save push notifications from Firebase.

My question is How can I save the push notification when opening the app without clicking on the notification.

I implemented the fcm and I can get notifications when app is running (`onMessage`) / in background (`onResume`) / terminated (`onLaunch`),

I can save them locally to a repository using the above functions, however those are only called when user click on the notification, and not when the app is started using its icon.

I tried to save in `onBackgroundMessage` but it's never called, below is the testing function trying to print something when onBackgroundMessage, it is outside the App class:

```
Future<void> testing(Map<String, dynamic> message) {
  print("BACKGROUND MSG CALLED");
  return Future.value(null);
}
```

below is the code I run in the initState(),

ps. _showNotification will also call saveNotifcation() which works well.

```
firebaseMessaging.configure(
    onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> msg) async {
    print("onMessage called $msg");
    await _showNotification(msg);
  },
   onBackgroundMessage:
       Platform.isAndroid ? testing : null,
  onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> msg) async {
    // give time for splashscreen to run and finish before it's done.
    SchedulerBinding.instance
        .addPostFrameCallback((_) => _showNotification(msg));
  },
  onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> msg) async {
    print("onResume called $msg");
    await _showNotification(msg);
  },
);
firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
    const IosNotificationSettings(
        sound: true, badge: true, alert: true, provisional: true));
firebaseMessaging.onIosSettingsRegistered
    .listen((IosNotificationSettings settings) {
  print("ios registered");
});
firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((){ print("printing Token: {$token}");});
```

I searched a lot but no solution could be found. any help will be much appreciated.

I'm using   firebase_messaging: ^7.0.0

Flutter doctor -v:

```
    [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.0, on Mac OS X 10.15.1 19B88, locale en)
    • Flutter version 1.22.0 at /Users/mine/flutter
    • Framework revision d408d302e2 (9 days ago), 2020-09-29 11:49:17 -0700
    • Engine revision 5babba6c4d
    • Dart version 2.10.0
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/mine/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/mine/Library/Android/sdk
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android
      Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.3.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.3.1, Build version 11C504
    • CocoaPods version 1.9.3

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 46.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 193.7361
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.49.3)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.15.0

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Mi 9T Pro (mobile) • 83b222f7 • android-arm64 • Android 10 (API 29)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Ok so thanks to this [link] (https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1660), I know now that in order to activate that function I need to remove the notification body in the push notification sent, only send the data body. while that doesn't allow for an actual notification to show to user, when app is close or in background, seems like a simple solution is to send the notification twice once as an actual notification goes to android notification center, another to the app using data.

Comment: Thanks! This really helped, i was racking my brain trying to get it to work on both iOS and Android, and your workaround is so simple, just send both haha!

Answer (score 0):

`onBackgroundMessage` is only called when the notification body is empty on the message when the app is in the background. More details is discussed in the [docs](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage#background-messages).